# Deep neural network class assignment based on probability

Tags: machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I'm creating anti-phishing algorithm and I am facing problem of final labeling.
The possible labels are **-1, 0, 1**.
My neural network build is:

```
def create_model(self, n_hidden = 1, n_neurons = 30, learning_rate = 3e-3, input_shape = 30):
        model = Sequential()
        model.add(InputLayer(input_shape = input_shape))
        
        for layer in range(n_hidden):
            model.add(Dense(n_neurons, activation = "relu"))
        model.add(Dense(n_neurons, activation="softmax"))
        model.add(Dense(1))
        optimizer = SGD(learning_rate = learning_rate)
        model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer = optimizer, metrics=BinaryAccuracy())
        return model
```

The results I am getting
looks like this:

```
[ 0.9413019   0.23881185  0.34624332 ...  1.0277238  -1.0253198
 -1.0065029 ]
```

How can I make my network round the result to one of mentioned labels?

Comment: You are asking the wrong question, your learning setup in incorrect, you should have softmax at the output, and encode classes 0, 1, and 2 instead of the labels you have.

Comment: So I did just as you said and changed my classes labels.
I decided to simplify the problem for now by classifying only two classes 0, 1. 
My network has softmax activation method in output layer, but results I receive don't seem to look better, all outputs are '1'

Comment: @mmalagocki A softmax activation function with 1 unit will always output 1. So, try using 'sigmoid' activation function in the output layer.

Comment: Thank you, now it works perfectly I have achvieded accuracy around 97